# Where can I search for mathematics academic positions with English as the medium of instruction in Thailand?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, thailand

I am a PhD candidate in mathematics going to graduate next March 2022 and am searching for academic positions beginning next year. I am using mathjobs.org and JREC-IN.

mathjobs.org has advertisements of academic positions all over the world, but I feel that many are not listed. JREC-IN has many advertisements for Japan. It has been difficult to find information about jobs in some parts of the world. For those parts of the world, even going to their math department websites they might not have English versions.

I would like to ask how to search for jobs in Thailand and in particular those seeking someone who can teach in English?

Comment: Google: math teaching iin English in Thailand. Likely most of what you find is pre-college, though. Add "college teaching" and it might improve things.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your suggestion, let me try.

Comment: I would suggest you to search math bachelor/master/PhD taught in English programs in Thailand. Then send cold e-mails to inquire for any possible openings.

Comment: @scaaahu Thank you for your suggestion, let me try.

Comment: I hope you got my point. Search for the programs for the **students**, not for teaching jobs. Once you find those programs, you know where your opportunities could be. Then send e-mails to inquire.

Comment: @scaaachu I found some places where maths is instructed in English, but no information about becoming a professor there, so I guess you are right that I should ask them directly.